# How to pass an out parameter in oracle stored procedure for python

Tags: oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I have a question, I've tried to pass an out parameter but appears an error, this is my code:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
lOutput = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
lOutput.setvalue(0, '')
cursor.callproc("SOME_PROC',[lOutput])
return lOutput .getvalue(0)
```

Please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting? That code looks pretty close. If you are calling a procedure with a pure out parameter then you don't need to set the value.

Comment: If I commented that line It generate this error message: Traceback (most recent call last):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change the last line like this

```
return lOutput .getvalue()
```

And it runs.